# Extraer números que inicien con 0 de $_GET['url']?

Tags: php, lógica

Temgo un problema de logica ,Estoy tratando de extraer los numeros de una url por ejemplo:

> http://localhost/apiescuela/tareas/888888

esto imprime

> 888888

Cuando  en la url en envían un numero normal  todo funciona correctamente.

El problema ocurre cuando me envían un numero que inicia con CERO y tiene mas numeros por ejemplo :

http://localhost/apiescuela/tareas/088888

No imprime nada...

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```html
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
            $var = $_GET['url'];
            $numero = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$var),10);
             print_r($numero);
}
```

Comment: y llega un "0" en medio de la url si te lo imprime ? por ejemplo: <http://localhost/apiescuela/tareas/8880888>

Comment: El problema es que estás convirtiendo el valor a entero con `intval`.  Si lo pones así `$numero =preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$var);` te funciona. Si quieres un entero realmente con sus `0` a la izquierda tendrás que usar una función *zerofill*.

Comment: si lo permite  incluso si llega solo un cero lo permite

http://localhost/apiescuela/tareas/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP no es un lenguaje tan *estricto*  como otros. Por ejemplo, con el manejo de números PHP es algo libre y se pueden hacer cosas que otros lenguajes no te permiten.

En tu caso el problema es que al convertir a entero con `intval` PHP te quita los ceros que hay a la izquierda, dado que no sirven para nada en un entero.

Si tú tratas el valor como una cadena no vas a tener ningún problema:

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
            $var = $_GET['url'];
            $numero =preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$var);
             print_r($numero);
}
```

Fíjate que incluso puedes hacer operaciones con ese valor.

Probemos:

```
$var="088888";
$numero = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$var);
echo "Tratado como cadena tenemos: $numero".PHP_EOL;
$suma=$numero+1;
echo "Sumamos 1 a $numero : $suma";
```

**Salida:**

```
Tratado como cadena tenemos: 088888
Sumamos 1 a 088888 : 88889
```

---

**NOTA:**

Quizá en este caso no sea necesario usar expresiones regulares para algo tan sencillo como obtener la última parte de la URL. Podrías recurrir a métodos más ligeros, como un simple `explode`:

```
$url="http://localhost/apiescuela/tareas/0888888";
$urlParts = explode('/',$url);
$lastPart = end($urlParts);
echo $lastPart;
```

**Salida:**

```
0888888
```